# Does Value Changed event work for Text Fields at all in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, event-handling, interface-builder

I'm trying to set up methods to be executed when value of certain text field is changed and saved. I tried to hook up this method with Value Changed event in Iterface Builder. It doesn't respond and I use this same event with some other control/classes and it works.

There is also no delegate method usable for that purpose.

Last resort could be only UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification notification or UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification notification, but I would certainly like to avoid writing observers if simple event in interface builder serves the purpose.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The valueChanged event is for buttons and sliders. For TextFields you'll want to use the Editing Changed, Editing Did Begin and Editing Did End events.

If that doesn't help become a UITextFieldDelegate instead.